# Trying to insert a sphere defect (.ply) into an object (.obj) using Voxel Method bypassing Airspaces and Vertices using the open3d

Tags: python, vtk, voxel, open3d, trimesh

get_voxel_center() doesn't work in the code below:

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

def main():
    # File paths for the try.obj and sphere.ply files
    try_obj_path = '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/try.obj'
    defect_path = '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Project Defect/sphere.ply'

    # Load meshes
    try_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(try_obj_path)
    defect_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(defect_path)

    # Apply transformations if needed (scaling, translation, rotation)
    scaled_defect = defect_mesh.scale(0.5, center=defect_mesh.get_center())

    # Convert meshes to voxel grids
    voxel_size = 0.2  # Adjust voxel size as needed
    try_voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_triangle_mesh(try_mesh, voxel_size)
    defect_voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_triangle_mesh(scaled_defect, voxel_size)

    # Get coordinates of occupied voxels in the try.obj mesh
    occupied_voxels_coords = np.array(try_voxel_grid.get_voxels())

    # Select a random occupied voxel
    voxel_index = np.random.randint(0, len(occupied_voxels_coords))
    selected_voxel = occupied_voxels_coords[voxel_index]

    # Translate the defect to the selected voxel's position
    translation_vector = try_voxel_grid.get_voxel_center(selected_voxel)
    scaled_defect.translate(translation_vector)

    # Merge meshes
    combined_mesh = try_mesh + scaled_defect

    # Visualize combined mesh
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([combined_mesh])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To bypass get_voxel_center(), I manually calculated center but this error still persist:

```
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np

def main():
    # File paths for the try.obj and sphere.ply files
    try_obj_path = '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/try.obj'
    defect_path = '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Project Defect/sphere.ply'

    # Load meshes
    try_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(try_obj_path)
    defect_mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(defect_path)

    # Apply transformations if needed (scaling, translation, rotation)
    scaled_defect = defect_mesh.scale(0.5, center=defect_mesh.get_center())

    # Convert meshes to voxel grids
    voxel_size = 0.2  # Adjust voxel size as needed
    try_voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_triangle_mesh(try_mesh, voxel_size)
    defect_voxel_grid = o3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.create_from_triangle_mesh(scaled_defect, voxel_size)

    # Get coordinates of occupied voxels in the try.obj mesh
    occupied_voxels_coords = np.array(try_voxel_grid.get_voxels())

    # Select a random occupied voxel
    voxel_index = np.random.randint(0, len(occupied_voxels_coords))
    selected_voxel = occupied_voxels_coords[voxel_index]

    # Compute the voxel center based on its index and size
    voxel_center = np.array(selected_voxel) * voxel_size + voxel_size / 2

    # Translate the defect to the selected voxel's position
    scaled_defect.translate(voxel_center)

    # Merge meshes
    combined_mesh = try_mesh + scaled_defect

    # Visualize combined mesh
    o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([combined_mesh])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here are both the errors for the 2 codes above respectively:

```
(base) xd_anshul@MacBook-Air ~ % python -u "/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Project Defect/voxel_open3d.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Project Defect/voxel_open3d.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Project Defect/voxel_open3d.py", line 29, in main
    translation_vector = try_voxel_grid.get_voxel_center(selected_voxel)
AttributeError: 'open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.VoxelGrid' object has no attribute 'get_voxel_center'
```

```
(base) xd_anshul@MacBook-Air ~ % python -u "/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Project Defect/voxel_open3d.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Project Defect/voxel_open3d.py", line 41, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Project Defect/voxel_open3d.py", line 29, in main
    voxel_center = np.array(selected_voxel) * voxel_size + voxel_size / 2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.Voxel' and 'float'
```

Tried using trimesh as well as VTK library but voxelization is not happening which is necessary to insert the defect onto the solid region/part of the object and not in any of the airspace because the object is hollow and very dissimilar to the defect which is itself a sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `get_voxel_center_coordinate` instead of `get_voxel_center`. See open3d docs [here](https://www.open3d.org/docs/latest/python_api/open3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.html#open3d.geometry.VoxelGrid.get_voxel_center_coordinate).

```
translation_vector = try_voxel_grid.get_voxel_center_coordinate(selected_voxel.grid_index)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks it worked but got to know voxelization coul only return a number of points on the surface of the 3d structure. Any way to get the points inside the object. Tried RayCasting but that seems to be very expensive computationally and therefore hell slow :/

Comment: @AnshulDhingra - Not sure on what you are asking. You can create a new question with tag open3d and proper details with reproducible code and I will look into it. Dont forget to mark the answer.